# ThinkPad Thunderbolt 3 Dock Gen 2 does not support WQHD (3440 x 1440) on macOS

Tags: thunderbolt, dock

I just bought a ThinkPad Thunderbolt 3 Dock Gen 2 to dock my MacBook Pro 14-inch, 2021.

But for some reason, WQHD (3440 x 1440) is not working but lowering the resolution works fine. I have already updated the dock. Is there a macOS setting I am missing? It works great on my Linux laptop, even at 60hz.

edit: it's a 40AN

More details:
It's a hp e344c, and it works when using the HDMI Port of the MacBook and also if I just use a simple USB-C dongle with HDMI output.
The MacBook Pro has a Apple M1 Pro and is running macOS Ventura 13.5 (22G74).

Comment: How are you connecting, HDMI or DisplayPort?  I recommend the latter. Also, MBP 14"2021 is a bit vague.  Is it the M1Pro or M1Max?

Comment: 1) Does the screen work when connected directly to your MBP? 2) There is no reference to macOS on the dock's support page https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/pd500265-thinkpad-thunderbolt-3-dock-gen-2-overview-and-sevice-parts - it does seem very targeted for Windows. 3) What model of monitor?

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I have added more details about my setup. Yes, I think it is aimed at Lenovo laptops in particular, but I was hoping that Thunderbold would be standardised.

Comment: So we know the monitor (HDMI) is compatible with macOS. That leaves the dock (using HDMI) as the problem. Try dock Display Port to monitor Display port (as @Allan suggests). Otherwise, I am sorry to say, you have to give up with the dock and Macs.